# Detect how long the keyboard arrow key has been pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I know that how to detect the pressed key in Javascript by this way:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 37: // left
        break;

        case 38: // up
        break;

        case 39: // right
        break;

        case 40: // down
        break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

I want to know if it is possible that we can detect how long the arrow key has been pressed just for an scrolling function I need to work on.

Answer (score 1):

Catch the `keydown` event, start timer, and stop timer on `keyup` event.

```
(function() {
   var PRESSING = false;
   var timer;

   $(document).keydown(function(e) {

      //Ignore repeated event to be fired.
      //otherwise it will reset timer.
      if(e.which === 38 && PRESSING) {
         return e.preventDefault();
      }

      //Start timer
      timer  = Date.now();          
      console.log("Key press");
      PRESSING = true;
   });

   $(document).keyup(function(e) { 

      //On arrow key up, stop timer and log result
      if(e.which === 38) {
         PRESSING = false;
         var time = Date.now() - timer;
         console.log("Key pressed for " + time/1000+ "sec");
      }
      e.preventDefault();
   })
}());
```

Example http://jsbin.com/vowabiqelu/edit?js,console,output

Comment: alert("Key pressed for " + Math.round(time/1000)+ "sec"); // try this for getting second instead of miliseconds

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, if you are making a scrolling function you should start scrolling on `keydown` and stop on `keyup`. The keyup event can be set within the keydown event.

Provide a jsfiddle and I could help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var pressed = null;
            $(element).on('keydown', function(event) {
                 pressed = +new Date();
                  // do whatever else you need upon key down
                 });
           $(element).on('keyup', function(event) {
        var duration = +new Date() - pressed;
         pressed = null;
        // do whatever you need to do based on the duration of the press
      });
```